# Chromium: how to block promoted content advertisement on Twitter (uBlock Origin/uMatrix)

Tags: debian, chrome, adblock

Using Debian 10 with Chromium along with `uBlock Origin` and `uMatrix` extensions.

On Twitter, advertisement as promoted content are not blocked, How can we block such content with `uBlock/uMatrix` or any other underlying Linux's solution?

Comment: This question isn't related to Unix and Linux, it's about configuring your adblocker. I'd suggest asking the developers for help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about Unix or Linux, but configuring an AdBlocker.

Comment: While it is not Linux related directly, it's not either unrelated as the underlying system is Linux...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en) may be used with custom filter to block Twitter's Ads, here are some documentation/links on how to achieve that

[Link-1](https://www.reddit.com/r/uBlockOrigin/comments/aku0uo/cant_get_it_to_block_twitter_ads_promoted_tweets/), [link-2](https://malwaretips.com/threads/help-wanted-to-block-promoted-tweets-on-twitter.95123/), [link-3](https://gist.github.com/r00k/2f243be6c30325f6a9b31844d91fc910) and [link-4](https://flaviocopes.com/block-distractions-ublock-origin/)... you may for instance try adding the following on the custom filter list of uBlock Origin

```
twitter.com##.trends.Trends.module
twitter.com##.dashboard-right.dashboard
twitter.com##.module.DashboardProfileCard
!twitter.com##article:has-text(/Promoted|Gesponsert|Реклама|Promocionado|Sponsorisé/):xpath(../..)
twitter.com##:xpath(//span[(text()='Promoted' or text()='Gesponsert' or text()='Реклама' or text()='Promocionado'or text()='Sponsorisé']/../../../../..)
twitter.com##[data-testid="trend"]:has-text(/Promoted|Gesponsert|Реклама|Promocionado|Sponsorisé/):xpath(..)
```

Other additional filter may be added, this is provided as an example.

Comment: I had to add one closing paren to the second to last line to get this to work.

I only see English Twitter, so I took out the other languages, and the commented out section.